# Remote server changes $_SESSION['loggedIn'] to false but remains true on local host

Tags: php

This is my first time, so I may make some mistakes in presentation - apologies in advance!

I have a simple login check at the top of a Welcome page and at the top of page that the user navigates to from the Welcome page.

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] <> "true") {
    header('location: login.php');
exit;
}
?>
```

On my local host (using DevServer 17) when the Welcome page shows loggedIn = true, the next page also show true and opens correctly.  When I run on the remote server, the Welcome page shows loggedIn = true, but the next page shows loggedIn = false and sends me back to the login page.

I have tried adding

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

but no errors ever get reported. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. `E_NOTICE` level errors are just as important in my opinion. Do you have `session_start()` at the top of all pages that need to check `$_SESSION`?

Comment: whats the code on " the next page"

Comment: The PHP code on the next page is exactly the same as on the welcome page, and is present on all pages.

Comment: dont describe the code. post it

Comment: It is as above:<?php
// start session
session_start();
if($_SESSION['loggedIn'] <> "true") {
    header('location: login.php');
exit;
}
?>

Comment: Do you have anything at all before the `<?php` tag? I also suggest you set the `error_reporting` and `display_errors` in your `php.ini` file to avoid missing anything important.

Comment: Thanks Phil.  There is definitely nothing (no space) before the php tag.  Although I have a lot of experience in scientific programming, PHP and web stuff is new ground for me, so bear with me.  I can't find a php.ini file on my website? Where would it normally be?  Is it normally set up automatically or do I have to create it?  Apologies for the duh questions!

Comment: Phil: My hosting service has info on making PHP.ini file, so please ignore the last couple of questions.

Comment: @PhilWatson you should be able to drop a `.user.ini` file in the root of your project with the error reporting settings. See http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php